# Spring intercept-url patterns

Tags: spring-security

what is the difference between a Spring Security intercept-url pattern with path/** or path/*
I've seen some Spring security configurations that have the below, but I don't understand the /* vs /**

Comment: thanks, I'm new to the site and don't fully understand everything yet but I'll get there

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `/**` vs. `/*` is a pretty common thing in frameworks nowadays, and is generally referred to as `Apache Ant Pathing` or something similar. Basically, the difference between the 2 is that `/**` matches the entire directory tree, including subdirectories, where as `/*` only matches at the level it's specified at.

For example, suppose you had the following files

```
Main.java
directory/Main.java
```

Then

```
/*.java
```

Would match `Main.java`, but not `directory/Main.java`, whereas

```
/**/*.java
```

would match both.

Obviously the principles applies exactly the same for urls in Spring Security, just seemed to a bit easier to illustrate it via file names in this case.