# Spring security for REST controllers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am working with Spring MVC and Spring security for my REST controllers and documentation. I would like to protect three different paths:

- "/api/**"
- "/api-docs"
- "/api-documentation”

Obviously, this code only works for the last one: "/api-documentation". I have also tried antMatchers("/api/**","/api-docs","/api-documentation") but I do not know how to configure it right. Any ideas?

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
    .and()                  
    .antMatcher("/api/**")            
    .antMatcher("/api-docs") 
    .antMatcher("/api-documentation") 
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().hasRole("REST")
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario just was necessary to change the antmatcher to `.antMatcher("/api*")`  removing the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify who can access specified paths:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll() 
.antMatchers("/api-docs").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is my problem. Only these three paths need to be authenticated with the role "REST"

Comment: Would say that you need to authenticate each request anyRequest().authenticated() and add try to add hasRole for each path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some path matching suggestions.

`"/api/**"` will match all methods like `/api/x/y`.

`"/api-docs"` will only match with `/api-docs`. Likewise `/api-documentation`.

If you add `"/api-docs/*"` It will map `/api-docs/x`.

Here are [some](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) [useful](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240794/spring-intercept-url-patterns) on ant patterns.

Therefore something like,

```
http
.csrf().disable()
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
.and()                  
.antMatchers("/api/**","/api-docs","/api-documentation")
.authorizeRequests()
.anyRequest().hasRole("REST")
.and()
.httpBasic();
```

must work, according to your path specification requirement.

Comment: Thank you but .antMatcher("/api/**","/api-docs","/api-documentation") is an invalid operation.

Comment: Hi @maleenc, I supossed that is not a gramatical problem. The problem is I cannot put there this operation. (antMatchers). Thank you, I will use this: .antMatcher("/api*")